# C Code - Guessing Game - Function Issues

Tags: c, pointers

Ok, been looking at this for hours now and could be just because it's late, but I'm braindead. So the code is supposed to accomplish the following:

1. Display instructions
2. Ask user for number of games to play
3. For each game
   a.  get a letter from file
   b.  Play one game
   i.  While still has guesses
   ii. Get guess from player
   iii.    Compare guess to letter from file
   iv. If guess is correct, return 1
   v.  Else increase counter
   vi. Return 0 if  5 guesses incorrect
   c.  check for win or lose

This is the code I have so far, any ideas how to get this thing to run properly?:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define MAXGUESSES 5
#include <stdio.h>


//Pre-Processor Directives

void gameRules();
//Game Instructions

int singleGame(char fileLetter);
//Checks guesses, returns 0 after 5 incorrect attempts

char retrieveGuess();
//Prompts user for guess and returns guess
//Called from inside singleGame function

int guessedIt(char answer, char inputLetter);
//Lets user know if answer comes before or after their guess.
//Returns 1 if answer is correct, and 0 for incorrect.
//Called from inside singleGame function.




int main()
{
    char fileLetter = 'a';
    FILE* filePtr;
    int numOfGames = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    //run it

//Rules of Game
gameRules();

//File pointer that opens the file, "r" stands for reading the file
filePtr = fopen("lettersin.txt", "r");

/* File checking if-else

if (filePtr == NULL)
{
    printf("I don't exist");
}
else
{
    printf("I'm alive");
}
*/  

printf("How many games would you like to play? (Pick from 1-4)\n");
scanf("%d", &numOfGames);

for (counter = 0; counter < numOfGames; counter++)
{
    //Pulls a letter from the file and writes it to variable "fileLetter"
    //Note to self: make sure to include "filePtr" so fscanf knows where to pull from
    fscanf(filePtr, " %c", &fileLetter);
    singleGame(fileLetter);
}

//Closes file, not necessary now, but good for later on in bigger programs that may need more files
fclose(filePtr);
return 0;
}

//Game rules function
void gameRules()
{
printf("Welcome to the Letter Guessing Game\n");
printf("You will enter the number of games you want to play (1-4 games).\n");
printf("You have 5 chances to guess each letter.\n");
printf("Let's begin:\n");
}

//Single Game Function
int singleGame(char fileLetter)
{
int numGuesses = 0;

while (numGuesses < MAXGUESSES)
{
    retrieveGuess();
    numGuesses = numGuesses + 1;
}

return 0;
}

//Guess retrieval function
char retrieveGuess()
{
char inputLetter;
printf("What is your guess? (Lowercase letters only, please)\n");
scanf(" %c", &inputLetter);
int guessedIt(char fileLetter, char inputLetter);
}

//Correct, or not, function
int guessedIt(char fileLetter, char inputLetter)
{
if (fileLetter == inputLetter)
{
    printf("You guessed it!\n");
    return '1';
}

else if (inputLetter < fileLetter)
{
    printf("The letter comes after your guessed letter.\n");
    return '0';
}

else
{
    printf("The letter comes before your guessed letter.\n");
    return '0';
}
}
```

Comment: What's improper about how it's running now?

Comment: Whats this `return '1';` why not just `return 1;` ?

Comment: What is returning `retrieveGuess()`?. Maybe you just need to sleep :)

Comment: the returned value from `fopen()` should always be checked, I.E. a very bad programming practice to comment out the error checking.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

```
//Single Game Function
int singleGame(char fileLetter)
{
    int numGuesses = 0;

    while (numGuesses < MAXGUESSES)
    {
        retrieveGuess();
        numGuesses = numGuesses + 1;
        // You should return 1 here if the guess is right, no?
        // Something like:
        // char guessedChar = retrieveGuess();
        // place call for function guessedIt here and if it
        // is 1 return the result (if it's 0, don't return, let it keep looping)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This function:

```
//Guess retrieval function
char retrieveGuess()
{
char inputLetter;
printf("What is your guess? (Lowercase letters only, please)\n");
scanf(" %c", &inputLetter);
int guessedIt(char fileLetter, char inputLetter);
}
```

Isn't returning anything. You need a return statement for each function that you define as returning something. Also, I don't think the last statement even makes sense, just return `inputLetter`

This function:

```
//Correct, or not, function
int guessedIt(char fileLetter, char inputLetter)
{
    if (fileLetter == inputLetter)
    {
        printf("You guessed it!\n");
        return '1';
    }

    else if (inputLetter < fileLetter)
    {
        printf("The letter comes after your guessed letter.\n");
        return '0';
    }

    else
    {
        printf("The letter comes before your guessed letter.\n");
        return '0';
    }
}
```

Is returning a `char` ('1'/'0') even though it declares to be returning an `int`. You want to write `return 1;`/`return 0;`. You should place it where I put the comments